# I'm new to Django and I'm having trouble displaying categories in this website

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

**Models.py**

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64, default="")
    bid = models.ForeignKey(Bid, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="listing", default=None,)
    description = models.TextField(default="")
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="listings", default="")
    is_closed = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
    watchlist = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name="watching")
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="listing", null=False, blank=True, default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
#the category class
class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.category
```

**Views.py**
*This is where I think the problem is because i'm not very familiar with the methods, if I **use** category = request.POST["category], I get an error saying multivalue dict..., I'm just stuck here if you have a clue how i can modify this method to show the items in a category *

````
def categories(request):
category = request.POST("category")
listings = category.listings.all()
    
return render(request, "auctions/categories.html", { "listings":listings })
```
````

**categories.html**

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h2>Categories</h2>
    
    <form action="{% url 'categories' %}" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="categories">Category</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="categories" id="categories">
          {% for category in categories %}
          <option>{{category}}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
      </div>        
    </form>

    
    {% for listing in listings %}
    {% if not listing.is_closed or user == listing.bid.user %}
     <p></p>   
    <div class="card" style="width: 60rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" style="width: 20rem;" src="{{listing.image_url}}" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{listing.title}}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">{{listing.description}}</p>
          <p>Bid: {{listing.bid}}</p>
          <p>Created {{listing.date}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <a href="{% url 'listing' listing.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p></p>
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not receiving anything as POST, so there wouldn't be any value there.

Your lines of:

```py
category = request.POST("category")
listings = category.listings.all()
```

make no sense because:
in `category = request.POST("category")` you are first trying to store something into category from the POST which #1 doesn't exist and #2 would be a string even if it did.

Let's just assume there is something in the POST with the key "category", you then try to receive all the listings using the category variable. Since you didn't define category variable properly, there's no way this would work anyways. Assuming for one second that you had, the Category object you defined in your models has no listings field or relation.

The correct way to do this would be:

```py
category = Category.objects.get(category="Name Of Category You Set")
listings = Listing.objects.filter(category=category)
```

But before you go ahead and do anything, I really recommend you learn more about Objects and classes because seeing your above attempts you seem to lack knowledge of not only those but of variables swell.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will read more on those topics, but the idea is for the user to choose a category and then get all the listings in that category, so with the form in the categories page, I thought it would post the category the user selected and then use it to get the listings

Comment: @maestro anyways, you would need to add a form with the method POST, and then add a check using request.method to see if it is POST, and then get the name of the of the category from request.POST and get the category from Category.objects.get(category=request.POST[‘category’])

Comment: @DillsPickle thank you, I'm getting this error (MultiValueDictKeyError at /categories 'category') probably because of this line, categories = Category.objects.get(category=request.POST['category']). but check out updated code please.

Comment: @DillsPicke check the question out at - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66566079/multivaluedictkeyerror-at-categories-category